# Unity Resolve c#

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm facing of a kind of issue inside my app :

```
public interface IOrderServiceTest1 : IEntityBaseRepository<Order>
{
}

public class OrderServiceTest1 : IOrderServiceTest1
{
}
```

In my web Api config class I try to resolve this :

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>), typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>));
container.RegisterType<IOrderServiceTest1, OrderServiceTest1>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Then when I try to resolve error is showing up :

```
IOrderServiceTest1 myServiceInstance = container.Resolve<IOrderServiceTest1>();
```

> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, ....Data.Repositories.EntityBaseRepository`1[...Entities.Order], is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Here the IEntityBaseRepository :

```
    public interface IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
    IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetSingle(int id);
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
}
```

Can I have some help to resolve this kind of issue ?

thx

Comment: Show the `IEntityBaseRepository`

Comment: @CallumLinington :     public interface IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
    {

Comment: No, add the implementation to the original question.

Comment: @CallumLinington Done ;)